# get the value of x and y of UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to get the location of UILabel programatically. How can I do it, i.e. get the x and y of UILabel?

I tried `textAlert.center.y` or `textAlert.center.x` (`textalert` is the name of UILabel).

Comment: Is the name `textalert` or `textAlert`?

Answer (score 11):

It is the `frame` property that you are looking for. Try that.

```
textAlert.frame.origin.x
textAlert.frame.origin.y
textAlert.frame.size.width
textAlert.frame.size.height
```

Comment: @Tushar as Alexsander Akers pointed out, ivars aren't case insensitive. Since you don't seem to be mentioning an error, you might've defined both.

Comment: this should work, are you sure you dont have a null reference? What code initializes your UILabel and what are you currently getting from deepak's code?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on which part of the view you want the coordinates of.

`frame.origin` - Returns top left corner
`center` - Returns the center of the view
`CGRectGetMinX(frame)` - Gets x-coord of left edge.
`CGRectGetMinY(frame)` - Gets y-coord of top edge.
`CGRectGetMidX(frame)` - Gets x-coord of center.
`CGRectGetMidY(frame)` - Gets y-coord of center.
`CGRectGetMaxX(frame)` - Gets x-coord of right edge.
`CGRectGetMaxY(frame)` - Gets y-coord of bottom edge.